# How does the present perfect link the present with the past?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

How can I determine the meaning of a sentence written in the present perfect?

For example,

> I have played football for the national team.

Does this sentence necessarily imply that I am still playing for them or could it imply other meanings?

Comment: No,  it doesn't.

Comment: Well, how can I know the intended meaning of a sentence in the present perfect? I mean how can I determine whether the action is ongoing or it is finished and we are focusing on the result?

Comment: My comment was not intended as a complete answer (which is why I didn't put it in the answer box).  You have to use context, and it's not easy to explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence means that you have the experience of playing for the national team, and suggests nothing about whether you will continue playing for them or not. The type of team dictates what other inferences we can make.

As national sporting events tend to occur on yearly cycles, with different players being invited to play each year, it makes sense that a national team player could say this because they don't want to assert they're going to be invited back.

But if you change the example to a regular club team, it sounds like it's finished in the past because club team members are on the team indefinitely, so if they're not playing for the team at the moment, then there's no reason to think they will again:

> I have played football for Manchester United.

This is equivalent to "I used to play for Manchester United".

Answer (score -2):

The *present perfect* tells about things in the past - period. It tells nothing about the present:

> I have played football for the national team.

This means you have done so. You may do the same today or tomorrow or not again at all. There is no further implication.

There is the *present perfect progressive* for activities taking place in the past *up to now*:

> I have been playing football for the national team.

That means you have done so in the past (perhaps several times so) but you just stopped and won't do it any more.

Comment: "It tells nothing about the present" -  no, but learners are sometimes told that it refers to the past in relation to the present. _I have done the task_ - I finished it a short time ago and you can see the result, versus __I did the task_ (maybe a long time ago).  But this doesn't always apply. _I have played football for the national team_ means that that is among my achievements, not that I have just finished doing so.

Comment: False. The present perfect tell us about the present *by reference to events in the past*. Every present perfect sentence is, at least indirectly, about the present. Sentences just about the past, period, are in the *simple past*. The OP's sentence has the present meaning that right now they have the experience or achievement of playing on the national team. Also, the progressive version does not imply that they've stopped playing.